# Can you dispel the Slow effect of a Stone Golem?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, conditions

A [Stone Golem](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/stone-golem) has the ability to create a slow effect on nearby creatures:

> ***Slow (Recharge 5-6).*** The golem targets one or more creatures it can see within 10 feet of it. Each target must make a DC 17 Wisdom saving throw against this magic. On a failed save, a target can't use reactions, its speed is halved, and it can't make more than one attack on its turn. In addition, the target can take either an action or a bonus action on its turn, not both. These effects last for 1 minute. A target can repeat the saving throw at the end of each of its turns, ending the effect on itself on a success.

This is similar to, but not the same as the results of the [*slow*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/slow) spell.

Can you use *dispel magic* to remove this effect? It isn't technically a spell, even though it is magical.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## No, this doesn't work.

[*Dispel Magic*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/dispel-magic) specifically states:

> Any **spell** of 3rd level or lower on the target ends.

The Stone Golem's Slow ability is not a spell.

For further evidence, we can look at the [Sage Advice Compendium](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=14):

> **Can you use *dispel magic* to dispel a magical effect like a vampire’s Charm ability or a druid’s Wild Shape?** *Dispel magic* has a particular purpose: to break other spells. It has no effect on a vampire’s Charm ability or any other magical effect that isn’t a spell.